# Trying to restrict size limit for int datatype in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fix the size range of `int` datatype textbox to only two digits.
But I'm not able to so. Any idea would be appreciated.

`CoilEntry.cs` is the model class where `OUT_P_NO` is the `int` property I would like to restrict to a maximum of two digits.

`CoilEntry.cshtml` shows its html part.

**Coilentry.cs** (model class)

```
public class CoilEntry
{
    [Range(0,99, ErrorMessage="Please use values between 0 to 30")]
    public int OUT_P_NO { get; set; }
}
```

**CoilEntry.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CoilEntry", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">
                    Coil Entry Detail
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    OUT PART NO
                </td>
                <td>
                   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.OUT_P_NO,new {@type="number",@maxlength=2,@size=2})
                  </td>
</table>
}
```

The expected result would be that the textbox would only allow values from 0 to 99.

Currently, the textbox allows only numeric values, but value beyond two digits can be entered.

Comment: It might let you enter anything, but It should give you an error if you actually try to submit a value greater than 99 though.

Comment: Mohan, did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change to @type = "text" and add event for `keypress`

Add this to script section of page in cshtml file. `#OUT_P_NO` is id generate when use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OUT_P_NO`

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#OUT_P_NO').keypress(function(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                return false;
            return true;
    });
</script>
```

Change type="number" to "text"

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OUT_P_NO, new { @type = "text", @maxlength = 2, @size = 2 })
```

Comment: So many ways for this not to work and even breaks expected user input.